# How to check the convexity of a constrained set

Tags: convex-analysis

Say that we have the following matrices: $A\in M_{n,n}$ which is unknown, $Y\in M_{n,m}/\{0_{n,m}\}$ and $X\in M_{n,m}/\{0_{n,m}\}$. I want to show that the following set is convex $\Omega=\{S\in M_{m,m},\space S=(Y-A\times X)^T(Y-A\times X)\space \space |\space \space\|A\|_2\leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}\}$.

From the norm equivalence we have $\|A\|_2\leq \|A\|_1 \leq n\|A\|_2$ we have only n this is because A is a square matrix of dimension n and so $n=m$. What I would like to have as a constraint is $\|A\|_1\leq \epsilon$ but this will make the set a polygon having parabolas for each side which not convex.. so if we assume that $\|A\|_2\leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}$, then $\|A\|_1\leq \epsilon$. I'm considering $\|A\|_2 \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ because the set would be convex and smaller than considering $\|A\|_1\leq \epsilon$ which is not convex.

So how can we prove that $\Omega$ is a convex set?

Comment: When writing $A\times X$ and $\times AX$, do you simply mean the product $AX$?

Comment: I think that I did a typo here

Comment: I have only the expression of $A\times X$ which is the regular matrix product AX.

Comment: Note that $A$ should not be given at the beginning. It ranges over all matrices which satisfy the constraint. Also, if you know the value of $\epsilon$ you should give it. Otherwise, you might as well replace $\epsilon/n$ by $\epsilon$.

Comment: What is $X$? What is its relationship to $\epsilon/n$? If $S$ is convex for arbitrary $X$, then the unconstrained $S$ is also convex, since you can simultaneously rescale $A$ and $X$.

Comment: Actually $A$ is not given here that's why we put the constraint on $\|A\|_2$ and $\epsilon$ is nothing but a sufficiently small number and n is given as mentioned above to be the dimension of A. More specifically the constraint comes from the norm equivalence where $n=m$ and another constraint $\|A\|_1\leq \epsilon$..

Comment: Again, if you don't say more on $\epsilon$ it does not make much sense to write $\epsilon/n$ rather than simply $\epsilon$.

Comment: Your claim that "without the constraint, the set is not convex" is not true if $X=0$. In this case, your set is a singleton, hence convex.

Comment: I just made some changes to explain more about $\epsilon$.

Comment: Larger? Actually $\Omega\subseteq \{bla|\|A\|_1\leq \epsilon\}$.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo again actually I'm trying to look for a solution inside this set that's why I want to make it smaller and I would like to make sure about the convexity..

Comment: And if we set $X=0$ does not have sense because we loose any dependance on $A$.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. If you want $X\neq 0$, you have to say it in your question.

Comment: Yes we should have $X$ different from $0$.